# How do you force TPaintBox to do a complete repaint from the OnPaint event after it was only partially obscured?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use the TPaintBox's Canvas property in the OnPaint event to paint graphical detail, but when I tab away to an application that only partially obscures the paintbox, only the obscured part gets repainted when I tab back to it even though my code repaints the whole ClientRect of the paintbox. Isn't the Canvas supposed to cover the complete control?

Comment: Only the obscured part needs to be repainted. Which makes one wonder how you can tell that only it is repainted.

Comment: @David, I noticed it because the paint event actually has some bug in it that caused it to paint differently the second time around. It is supposed to paint the same detail every time. I can fix the bug in a different way, but now it's bothering how one can force a complete repaint for a paintbox.

Comment: You can force a repaint by invalidating the window, or a specific rect. But you don't need to force a repaint. You should not force a repaint. Do not do that It's a massive waste of time to try to repaint something that does not need to be repainted. Do you want to introduce flicker?! So fix the actual bug and stop worrying about this.

Comment: @David, I'm worrying about it because I don't understand why the Canvas property doesn't always cover the whole client area. Does the device context that it encapsulates, have some hidden clipping when a partial repaint is required? I always thought that a control's canvas is always for the whole client area.

Comment: This is all handled by the system rather than Delphi.  Only part of the Window is invalid, so Windows asks you to paint to a DC that has a clipping region set up to contain the invalid region. The control's canvas is indeed the whole client area.  If you wanted to be cute, you might paint just to the clip box of the DC. Anyway, you entire premise is wrong. You absolutely do not want to force a repaint of the entire window.

Comment: @David, ok, that makes sense. So it's the DC that's restricting the region that updates the screen even though I repaint the full graphic via the canvas.

Comment: I believe that is so.  Call `GetClipBox` passing `Canvas.Handle` to check the clipping rect of the DC.  Log the value somewhere, e.g. Form.Caption.

Comment: For some reason GetClipBox always returns the full region.

Comment: OK, maybe I got that wrong. Certainly `BeginPaint` returns the paint rect in the `PAINTSTRUCT`. But you cannot obtain that information readily.